# CRTP: I can't get rid of duplicate code even with static polymorphism

Tags: c++, templates, static, crtp

**1. Problem Description**

I have two classes `Derived1` and `Derived2`. All functions are the same and most of them contain around 100 lines. **The only difference** are the static objects that are being manipulated. `Derived1` is manipulating `p1` and `Derived2` is manipulating `p2`. Both classes use static functions. But there is a ***constraint***, the object that is being manipulated can only be used inside the package.  The structure of the files is as follow:

```
/**
 * 
 * include/derived.hpp
 * include/derived1.hpp
 * include/derived2.hpp
 * 
 * src/point.hpp
 * src/derived.cpp
 * src/Derived1.cpp
 * src/derived2.cpp
 * 
 * Point is only visible in the package
 * */
```

---

**2. Question**

I don't see how static polymorphism can solve my problem. How can I have like a **common** function `create` that knows which static instance i am manipulating like `p1`or `p2` while taking into account the constraint that I stated earlier:  **the object that is being manipulated can only be used inside the package.**

---

**3. Source Code c++ 11 (i can't use newer versions)**

The source code is based on the following article [Static Polymorphism in C++](http://blog.aaronballman.com/2011/08/static-polymorphism-in-c/).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct Point{
    std::vector<int> points;
};

static Point p1;
static Point p2;

template< class Derived >
class Base {
public:
    static void create() {
        Derived::create();
    }
    
    static void replace() {
        Derived::replace();
    }
    
    static void clear() {
        Derived::clear();
    }
};
 
class Derived1: public Base< Derived1 > {
    friend class Base< Derived1 >;
private:
    static void create() {
       p1.points = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    }
    
    static void replace() {
       std::replace_if(p1.points.begin(), p1.points.end(), [](int x){return x > 4;}, 5);
       //100 more lines
    }
    
    static void clear() {
        p1.points.clear();
    }
};
 
class Derived2: public Base< Derived2 > {
    friend class Base< Derived2 >;
private:
   static void create() {
      p2.points = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    }
    
    static void replace() {
        std::replace_if(p2.points.begin(), p2.points.end(), [](int x){return x > 4;}, 5);
        //100 more lines same as derived 1
    }
    
     static void clear() {
        p2.points.clear();
    }
};


int main()
{
    Base< Derived1 >::create();
    Base< Derived2 >::create();
    
    Base< Derived1 >::replace();
    Base< Derived2 >::replace();
    
    Base< Derived1 >::clear();
    Base< Derived2 >::clear();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can't you have a `static DerivedX::Point& p = pX;`, and then use `p` in `Base`?

Comment: You using the wrong design for this kind of problem. This is supposed to be used when the derived classes does not share code, but a common interface. If they share code, that code should be in the base class. As a side note, having classes with only static functions that operate on global objects seem like an anti-pattern. Why do you have the classes at all? You can just have regular functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if you can get that to work with CRTP, but it is pretty easy by using non-type template parameters:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct Point {
    std::vector<int> points;
};

// Hides the points
class Encapsulate {
    template<Point &p>
    class C {
      public:
        static void create() {
            p.points = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
        }

        static void replace() {
            std::replace_if(
                p.points.begin(), p.points.end(), [](int x) { return x > 4; }, 5);
            // 100 more lines same as derived 1
        }

        static void clear() {
            p.points.clear();
        }
    };
    static Point p1;
    static Point p2;

  public:
    using C1 = C<p1>;
    using C2 = C<p2>;
};

// Need to define them out-of-line or use C++17 inline keyword above
Point Encapsulate::p1;
Point Encapsulate::p2;

using C1 = Encapsulate::C1;
using C2 = Encapsulate::C2;

// You can still get to it, but that is basically always possible.
template<class T>
struct extract_point;

template<template<Point &> class T, Point &p>
struct extract_point<T<p>> {
    static Point &point;
};
template<template<Point &> class T, Point &p>
Point &extract_point<T<p>>::point = p;

int main() {
    C1::create();
    C2::create();

    C1::replace();
    C2::replace();

    C1::clear();
    C2::clear();

    auto &p1 = extract_point<C1>::point;

    return 0;
}
```

This works for all static `Point`s (basically, the address has to be known at compile tiem for this to work). There is also no runtime overhead by indirection, since the compiler knows what `p` references at compile-time.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't really say what your question is. I don't think that should be a problem if you export the type aliases C1 and C2.

Comment: It seems OP doesn't want to expose `p1`/`p2`.

Comment: Ok, I think you should describe what you really want to do. As super said above, this classes with only static functions approach working on static objects seems a bit weird. Why do you want p1 and p2 to be static? Who should be able to have access? Why don't you want to expose them? Right now, it seems like you actually want a class with a private point member and then create two (maybe static) instances of that.

Comment: It's what they want in the design. We are doing a project with my friends. It's just they don't want to expose the points. They don't want them to be accessible. Without that i guess i'm stuck and ur solution is the only one that makes sense. Unless if I can make Point class noncopyable.

anyway thank u a lot for ur help

Comment: You can make the points static private data members of another class and make the typedefs public in that class. I will update my answer.